# Does subprocess.Popen.wait deadlock when using file type for stdout?

Tags: python, django, subprocess

Any help is appreciated. I have a [custom Django command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) and a method like the one below:

```py
def read_status_to_list(self) -> List[str]:
    with open('git.txt', 'w+') as temp:
        status = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'status'], stdout=temp)
        status.wait()  

        statuses = [line.split()[-1] for line in temp.readlines()
                    if 'modified:' in line
                    ]
    # remove file when done
    if os.path.isfile('git.txt'):
        os.remove('git.txt')
    return statuses
```

However, `statuses` is always empty even when `git status` produces a number of modified modules not added yet. I noticed a warning in the [wait](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) method:

> Warning: This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

Is this warning related to the problem, and how can I successfully complete this task using subprocess? Thank you.